# How to select and use the value of a srcset attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I'm setting up some code to dynamically change a specific button on the page based on information provided in a key. I am relatively new to programming and jQuery/JavaScript and I am thankful for all answers!

Problem: I want to save an URL that is a value of a `srcset` attribute so that it can be saved to the key for the changing of the button-link. There are a few `srcset` attributes and my needed value has a unique identifier in the URL (*e.g.* `www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/...` with `KQ4` being the unique identifier). The other `srcset` attributes have `KQ6`, `KQ2`, and so on, as an example.

How can I select my needed `srcset` attribute (as info: it is always in the same position under the `<picture>` tag) and save it's content to the key?

```
<div class="unique_img" style="margin-left: 0px;">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/... 2x" media="min-width: xx")>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ6/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ6/... 2x" media="min-width: yy")>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ8/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ8/... 2x" media="min-width: zz")>
  </picture>
</div>
```

I have tried various jQuery methods to get my needed `srcset` selected, but I am not able to search specifically for my `KQ4` one:

```
$("div.unique_img[srcset*=KQ4]") 
$("div.unique_img:contains('KQ4')") 
$('div.unique_img:nth-child(1)') 
$('div.unique_img').find('KQ4') 
$('div.unique_img .srcset') 
$("img[name*='KQ4']")
```

Expected outcome would be to get the whole URL from the needed 1st `srcset` and save it to a specific key. As of now I still haven't been able to figure out how to do it exactly.

A pointer to the appropriate part of the documentation would be enough as well, as I want to learn JavaScript!

Comment: `I have tried various $() jquery methods ...`  -- can you post your tried jquery's

Comment: Oh, sorry. Totally forgot this. Those were my tries:

$("div.unique_img[srcset*=KQ4]");
$("div.unique_img:contains('KQ4')");
$('div.unique_img:nth-child(1)');
$('div.unique_img').find('KQ4');
$('div.unique_img .srcset');
$("img[name*='KQ4']")

Any many more (I typed them directly into the console, as I am trying it live on the site)

Comment: You could really benefit from learning the basics of how jQuery selectors work. Since they are based on CSS, I'd recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: @billynoah thank you for the documentation! I'm more than happy to get to know this in more detail! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one solution is add the `KQ4` in the selector

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.unique_img source[srcset*="KQ4"]');

console.log(element.srcset);
```

```html
<div class="unique_img" style="margin-left: 0px;">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/... 2x" media="min-width: xx")>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ6/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ6/... 2x" media="min-width: yy")>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ8/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ8/... 2x" media="min-width: zz")>
  </picture>
</div>
```

another solution is select all elements, iterate over them and check the string value:

```js
var sources = document.querySelectorAll('.unique_img source');
var targetSource = null;
[...sources].forEach(function(source) {
    
    if(source.srcset.indexOf('KQ4') !== -1) {
        targetSource = source.srcset;
    }
});


console.log(targetSource);
```

```html
<div class="unique_img" style="margin-left: 0px;">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/... 2x" media="min-width: xx")>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ6/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ6/... 2x" media="min-width: yy")>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ8/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ8/... 2x" media="min-width: zz")>
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: Both work as good as one could imagine, thank you so much! Now I have to understand what exactly is happening here. Thank you so much!

Comment: @domix07 glad those solutions work for you, let me know if something is not clear

Comment: I have a question indeed: is there a way to save the value from `console.log` to a variable as a `string`? I tried using `JSON.stringify` but it didn't yield the wanted results (it wasn't turned to a `string`)

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution! `$('.unique_img source[srcset*="KQ4"]').attr('srcset')` is my code. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @domix07 `console.log()` is only used to log information in the console. to saved the value in a variable you can do something like `var myVariable =  document.querySelector('.unique_img source[srcset*="KQ4"]').srcset;` there is no jQuery needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.querySelectorAll('source').forEach(src=> {
  if(/KQ4/.test(src.srcset)) {
    // 'src' contains selection
  }
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('source').forEach(src=> {
  if(/KQ4/.test(src.srcset)) {
    console.log( src.media );
    // your selected source tag is in 'src'`
}});
```

```html
<div class="unique_img" style="margin-left: 0px;">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ4/... 2x" media="min-width: xx")>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ6/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ6/... 2x" media="min-width: yy")>
    <source srcset="www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ8/..., www.url.com/this-is-a-sample-image/KQ8/... 2x" media="min-width: zz")>
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, sadly this returns "undefined"?

Comment: @domix07 the above snippet not returns `undefined` - probably you have some bug in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt using `*` and `contains` should work, only mistake you did is you are trying to match the div content instead of source inside div content.

Try below code

```
$("div.unique_img  source[srcset*=KQ4]") // this will return matching image having matching `srcset`
```

Comment: Finally I get length = 1! So I wasn't that far away from a possible solution. That is so good to hear... Thank you for the help!

Comment: happy to help you :)